# jQuery Datepicker slide effect on change of the month

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using the [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to set up the dates and display them on an input. 
I want to create an effet like this: [DZS Calendar](http://3.s3.envato.com/files/48884909/index.html) so when i click on next or prev i want to change the month with **slide effect** animation.

Is there a way to accomplish this?
For example:

```
prev: function(){$month.toggle("slide");}
next: function(){$month.toggle("slide");}
```

or:

```
changeMonth: function(){$this.toggle("slide");}
```

how can I do this with *Datepicker*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onChangeMonthYear` to add a custom animation when the month changes.

Here's how to do it:

```
$("#textBox1").datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        $(".ui-datepicker").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 600);
    }
});
```

(this assumes that you're attaching a datePicker to a text box with an ID of "textBox1")

Here's a working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7x5ma/

Edit: Here's another jsFiddle, with an effect like the one you're describing (which isn't a **slide** effect, but a **fade** effect):

http://jsfiddle.net/7x5ma/1/

You just need to change the animation like this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker").hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Close but I don't think the OP wants the jerky change in your fiddle.

Comment: The change works fine here, that's a standard jQuery slide effect, and that's what the OP requested (in bold)

Comment: No, look at the example website he provided (DZS Calendar) and you'll see the effect he's after.

Comment: Quoting: "so when i click on next or prev i want to change the month with `slide effect` animation."

Comment: Congratulations on copy and pasting the OP's text. It still doesn't provide the effect the OP's after. It may be a start, but it's not what he wants.

Comment: I've updated my reply. Your sarcasm isn't necessary here, the OP is showing a page with a **fade** effect, but he said he wants a **slide** effect... go figure

Comment: Thank you so much @FilipposKarapetis for help, this is what I wanted. But the slide effect works only in -in and not in -out. I tried with `$(".ui-datepicker").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 600);` but this hide completely Datepicker.

Comment: @Fuiba glad to help :) You can chain the hide/show events to achieve an in-out effect, like this: $(".ui-datepicker").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 600).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 600);